# Matlab Sphere plot without using the Sphere Function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to draw a sphere in Matlab without using the Sphere Function. This is my code:

```
r = 2;
[ x,y ] = meshgrid(-4:0.1:4);
z = sqrt(r^2-x.^2-y.^2);
mesh(real(z));
hold on 
mesh(real(-z));
```

The code above does generate a sphere of equation r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2. The only problem is that there is a horizontal plane slicing the sphere.

My question is how can I plot a sphere that doesn't show the horizontal plane?

The reason I am not using a Sphere function is because I want to plot a surface equation. If I use the Sphere function then Matlab assumes my surface will be a sphere.

Comment: just loose the sqrt... and scale appropriately

Answer (score 5):

You should consider switching to polar coordinates. MATLAB can plot surfaces that are topologically equivalent to a rectangular mesh:

```
N = 20;
thetavec = linspace(0,pi,N);
phivec = linspace(0,2*pi,2*N);
[th, ph] = meshgrid(thetavec,phivec);
R = ones(size(th)); % should be your R(theta,phi) surface in general

x = R.*sin(th).*cos(ph);
y = R.*sin(th).*sin(ph);
z = R.*cos(th);

figure;
surf(x,y,z);
axis vis3d
```

[image: result]

The trick is that in polar coordinates you have a rectangular mesh.

As you can see in the above formulae, in this convention `theta` is the polar angle and `phi` is the azimuthal angle, as it is common in mathematics and physics. You can use `sph2cart` to do the transformation from spherical to Cartesian coordinates, but then you need to input azimuth and elevation for the angles, which have a bit different definitions.

Comment: @JohnDoe for the record, MATLAB has amazing help and online documentation, see `help axis` and `doc axis` :) `axis vis3d` forces the axes to have a fixed 1:1:1 unit ratio in order to get undistorted plots of 3d objects.

Answer (score 1):

im new here but i did made some for matlab without using sphere function
although with fmesh
divide the sphere in 2 parts and use 2 functions to plot on positive and one negative

im showing an example for one function could be

```
f=@(x,y) sqrt(3 - (sqrt(3).*(x-4)).^2 -  (sqrt(3).*(y-2)).^2)-5
              ^                ^                              ^
radius of the sphere    position on x axis            position on z axis
```

full code

```
f=@(x,y) sqrt(3 - (sqrt(3).*(x-4)).^2 -  (sqrt(3).*(y-2)).^2)-5
fmesh(f,[-10 10 -10 10],'ShowContours','on')

hold

f1=@(x,y) -sqrt(3 -  (sqrt(3).*(x-4)).^2 -  (sqrt(3).*(y-2)).^2)-5
fmesh(f1,[-10 10 -10 10],'ShowContours','on')

hold off
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there have certainly been nicer plots... but it works, if you just set the entry in the z-matrix to nan:

```
temp = real(z);
temp(temp==0) = nan;
```

Or you can go with an implicit 3D plot. In matlab file exchange you can find an according function ([Matlab File Excahnge](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23623-ezimplot3--implicit-3d-functions-plotter))
The corresponding script would look like this:

```
f = 'x^2 +y^2 +z^2 -4';
ezimplot3(f,[-5 5])
```